# install wkhtmltopdf for generating lot of pdf files on windows 8

Tags: php, html, pdf, laravel-4, wkhtmltopdf

Good day,

Is it possible to use wkhtmltopdf on laravel 4 using windows 8?? 
if it is, can you please help me to do that.

I was trying to generate a bunch of pdf files on my laravel 4 application, this is for the inventory items to be printed, I tried to use the dompdf, and it was very easy to use but when it comes to generating alot of pdf files (10pages+, full text just for testing) its kinda slow and consumes higher cpu usage, so I was thinking to switch on wkhtmltopdf because according to some reviews its much more efficient for generating a lot of pdf files and thats what Im needed on my application.

I tried to follow the installation direction on  [packalyst.com](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/ignited/laravel-pdf) but when i run, it gives me a

> proc_open(): CreateProcess failed, error code - 193

I think its because im using windows 8 and not linux.

Its better if you can suggest a better solution,

Thank you very much for your help! it is much appreciated.

-Melvn

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be the answer you're looking for, but I develop a web application which uses wkhtmltopdf, and my primary development is in windows. The way I am doing so is however simply by emulating Linux. I have used [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/) to put together a simple vagrant configuration, and then I use Vagrant combined with Virtualbox to make it easy to deploy my linux virtual machine on any windows machine I am doing development on.

Specifically, I needed to add the package "libxrender1" to ensure that wkhtmltopdf would have the library it required to function in my VM.